# Is there a way to make an Instagram account be as if it was a "new" account?

Tags: user-accounts, instagram

I have a question about Instagram: is there a way to make my Instagram account "be" as if it was a new one? Let me explain better: I made a comment on the profile of a brand ambassador and now several followers of her are coming to snoop on my profile and then pass on what I post to that ambassador, so I don't want my account to be visited by anyone who shouldn't or who has no good intentions about me.

If I change my username, will such people know that my profile is the same, that I am not another profile? Is there a way for me to make my current account "look like" a new account while maintaining my privacy? Or, is this only possible by creating a new account?